# Adding multiple values to a key in dictionary in Python

Tags: python

My code is as follows:

```
import re
import os
dict = {}
rpm_list = ['rpm1', 'rpm2', 'rpm3']
build_type = 'candidate'

for rpm in rpm_list:
    repo_path = '/product/Esoteric/candidate'
    if re.search(build_type, repo_path):
        if build_type in dict:
            dict[build_type].append(rpm)
        else:
            dict[build_type] = ''
    else:
        print ("None")

for key in dict:
    print (dict[key])
```

I have tried seeing other posts and using setdefault method. Not much help. 
The code fails with following error:

```
dict[build_type].append(rpm)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Can anyone help?
Expected output is: (there will be others keys as well.)

```
{'candidate': ['rpm1', 'rpm2', 'rpm3']}
```

Comment: append used for append new keys.. not for value append. what is your expected output.

Comment: How do I append values here, to the existing keys?

Comment: `dict[build_type] = ''` you set it to an empty string (there's no append for strings)... you want it to be equal to a list instead right?

Comment: provide input and expected output.

Comment: Thank you @abccd.. It helped. I wanted it to be equal to list. mistake there. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(list)
# name changed to dct as dict is builtin

# other stuff omitted
if re.search(build_type, repo_path):
    dct[build_type].append(rpm)  # any missing keys will generate a list
```